# Rails validation method comparing two fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

My model has two fields that i want to compare to each other as part of the validation. I want to be sure end_time is after start_time. I have written a validation method to compare them, but I must be doing something wrong, because the values are always nil.  Can someone help?

```
class LogEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :start_time, :presence => { :message => "must be a valid date/time" }
  validates :end_time, :presence => {:message => "must be a valid date/time"}
  validate :start_must_be_before_end_time

  def start_must_be_before_end_time
    errors.add(:start_time, "must be before end time") unless
       start_time > end_time
  end 
end
```

gets the error

```
undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass
```

So, start_time and/or end_time are nil.   I thought I was following the many examples I found, but apparently not. What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My best guess is you need your method to look like this:

```
private

def start_must_be_before_end_time
    errors.add(:start_time, "must be before end time") unless
        start_time < end_time
end
```

(Also, notice the `<` rather than `>` (or change to `if` and `>=`)

If this doesn't work then you should also check that `start_time` and `end_time` are being defined correctly in the controller as there can be funny things happen if the time is created across more than one form element.

**With Rails 7 `ComparisonValidator`**

Rails 7 has added the `ComparisonValidator` which allows you to use the convenience method [`validates_comparison_of`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods.html#method-i-validates_comparison_of) like so:

```
class LogEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_comparison_of :start_time, less_than: :end_time
  # OR
  validates_comparison_of :end_time, greater_than: :start_time
end
```

Find out more here: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods.html#method-i-validates_comparison_of

Comment: I was hopeful that the addition of "self" would make the difference, but I get the same error.  start_time and end_time have been working fine up until now, except that you can put the end before the start.  Guess I'll give up for now. Thanks.

Comment: Then I'm getting very suspicious about how start_time and end_time are being set in the controller. What sort of form element are you using for them?

Comment: start_time and end_time are each set with f.datetime_select.  I don't know why the values aren't available to validate - they are definitely there later.  I am new to Rails, am I misunderstanding?

Comment: That was it! The problem was with f.datetime_select.  I changed the form to just use a text field for entry and the values were there for the validation.  What I don't understand is why the rest of the code works with f.datetime_select?  When do start_time and end_time get set in that case?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Read this - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#using-date-and-time-form-helpers - it may explain enough for you to get back to using the datetime_select. The problem is that active record has to construct the date from 3 separate form components so the date is not returned as a single item in the params hash.

Answer (score 6):

You need to check for presence yourself (and skip the validation step if not present).

```
def start_must_be_before_end_time
  return unless start_time and end_time
  errors.add(:start_time, "must be before end time") unless start_time < end_time
end
```

Prints either "must be a valid date/time" OR "start time must be before end time".

Alternative

```
def start_must_be_before_end_time
  valid = start_time && end_time && start_time < end_time
  errors.add(:start_time, "must be before end time") unless valid
end
```

Prints "start time must be a valid date/time" AND "start time must be before end time" if start_time or end_time isn't set.

Personal preference for the **first**, since it only shows what the user did wrong. The latter is like many websites which just load off 20 lines of error text onto the user just because the programmer thought it would be nice to see every validation result. Bad UX.

Comment: Yup, tried that and it always just returns.  Doesn't fail, so that's good, but also doesn't compare the times...

Comment: Added the alternative which "checks" the date. You have to make sure that start_time and end_time is set, otherwise the validation won't be run of course (although the presence checks should prevent the record from being saved).

Comment: This prevented the nil problem, but also prevents valid dates from being added - I always get the "start time must be before end time" message now.

Answer (score 4):

### Clean and Clear (and under control?)

I find this to be the clearest to read:

#### In Your Model

```
# ...

validates_presence_of :start_time, :end_time

validate :end_time_is_after_start_time

# ... 

#######
private
#######

def end_time_is_after_start_time
  return if end_time.blank? || start_time.blank?

  if end_time < start_time
    errors.add(:end_time, "cannot be before the start time") 
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Ruby on Rails introduces in version 7.0 the [`validates_comparison_of`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#comparison) validator that covers use cases exactly like yours:

```
validates :start_time, comparison: { less_than: :end_date }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use validates_timeliness gem https://github.com/adzap/validates_timeliness

Answer (score 0):

`start_time.to_i < end_time.to_i`should fix it. You are trying to compare datetime but for some reason it can't, so convert them to int before comparing.